# Maximum call stack size exceeded many request to insert in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First, I apologize for my English, which is not very good.
I have a problem. I get a message "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I have multiple RESTful requests to be inserted into a database mongodb.
First it performs a "collection.find" so that only after doing the insert or update.
10000 requests sent with a loop for the test.
What can be causing the error and how can I solve?
Would have to put all requests in a queue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide some code and what you mean by "RESTful" requests. There's no built-in support for that in MongoDB, so it's something you've written.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help.
I managed to solve using "async.queue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly without code, but looping over 10000 items and performing an action sounds like a bad idea to me. Check out the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, specifically the [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function. This will loop in an asynchronous manner which might fix the issue you're having. If you post some code I can get more specific.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply.
I managed to solve using "async.queue".
When running the code in "parallel" error occurs, probably due to several processes "find, update" in various "collections".
Thank you!